# triangulation (ratio of areas)

Tags: geometry

Given is an isosceles triangle ABC. Let q be the ratio of the red and blue areas and T(x) be the lowest degree monic polynomial with integer coefficients and has x = q as one of its roots. Determine T(15).

[image: here is the figure]

Comment: Welcome to [Math SE!](https://math.stackexchange.com) . Please read this [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to begin with and share your thoughts and efforts in the question

Comment: Where does this question come from, please?

Comment: $q=2\cos{\frac{\pi}{5}}, T(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

Comment: I say, banana, WHERE DOES THIS QUESTION COME FROM, PLEASE?

Comment: Gerry Myerson, I got this from a facebook group.

Comment: And where did the facebook group get it from, banana?

Comment: Gerry Myerson, I don't know.

Comment: Can you find out, please?